# Overriding draw function in UIView class of iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I created a class from UI view and below is code.

```
class HudView: UIView {
    var text = ""

    class func hud(inView view: UIView, animated: Bool) -> HudView {
        let hudView = HudView(frame: view.bounds)
        hudView.isOpaque = false
        view.addSubview(hudView)
        hudView.show(animated: animated)
        return hudView
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let boxWidth: CGFloat = 96
        let boxHeight: CGFloat = 96

        let boxRect = CGRect(x: round((bounds.size.width - boxWidth) / 2), y: round((bounds.size.height - boxHeight) / 2), width: boxWidth, height: boxHeight)

        let roundRect = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: boxRect, cornerRadius: 10)
        UIColor(white: 0.3, alpha: 0.8).setFill()
        roundRect.fill()

        if let image = UIImage(named: "Checkmark") {
            let imagePoint = CGPoint(x: center.x - round(image.size.width / 2), y: center.y - round(image.size.height / 2))
            image.draw(at: imagePoint)

        }
        let attribs = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16), NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]

        let textSize = text.size(withAttributes: attribs)
        let textPoint =  CGPoint(x: center.x - round(textSize.width / 2), y: center.y - round(textSize.height / 2) + boxHeight / 4)
        text.draw(at: textPoint, withAttributes: attribs)
    }

    func show(animated: Bool) {
        if animated {
            alpha = 0
            transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                self.alpha = 1
                self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            })
        }
    }
```

When I am creating object of this class, I observed that I don't need to call "draw" function separately and it still draws from this function. Could you help what is the reason, I don't need to call this function on HudView's object.

Below is code for creating object from class and even without calling "draw" func, it is still able to draw with given specifications.

```
let hudView = HudView.hud(inView: navigationController!.view, animated: true)
hudView.text = "Tagged"
```

Answer (score 0):

from here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622529-draw

"This method is called when a view is first displayed or when an event occurs that invalidates a visible part of the view. You should never call this method directly yourself"